# android emulator hangs on Mac

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-mac

When I launch my Android emulator on Mac, it just comes up with the "Android" screen and won't go any further. Is there a source for emulator definitions that reliably work?

When I try to launch an app (from Visual Studio Mac), the specific error message is

```
Error: Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running?
```

That said, I've found this to be an ongoing problem, in the sense that the emulator manager has too many choices. All I really care about is getting an emulator at a specific API level that actually launches, preferably quickly.

[image: emulator details]

My Mac is running Sierra 10.13.4. It's a 2013 Macbook Pro with 16GB of ram.

Comment: Please provide some more information in question about Emulator specs etc

Comment: config of your mac ?

Comment: There is something below `AVD details` popup. Did you check what is the error message? Is it same what you have posted above in question?

Comment: You could try using the predefined Device Definitions, preferably an x86, no?